# flask api returning 500 when importing custom class

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Below is the piece of code that i have for my api and i have a class auths which has method createuser returning simple int value as of now but when i hit with restapi is gives error. Any idea ?

api.py

```
from auths import auths
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def api_root():
    #m = auths.createuser()
    return "m"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

auths/auths.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class auths:
    def createuser():
        return 1
```

Error:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: To debug more easily you can turn on debug mode via `app.run(debug=True)` or by setting debug to true in the config. That way you will not (only) see a 500 html error but the python error that lead flask to emit a 500er. Only use debug mode in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the argument `self` for the class functions,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class auths:
    def createuser(self):
        return 1
```

Another problem with the function call,

```
m = auths()
result = m.createuser()
```

You have to call like this, result will have value `1` as the class function returns.